# Dynamic object creation in method/function arguments

Tags: java, scala, orc

I am generating orc files using the following

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc._;

val orcLine:OrcStruct = OrcUtils.createOrcStruct(
                        typeInfo,
                        new Text(value1),
                        new Text(value2),
                        new Text(value3),
                        new Text(value4),
                        new Text(value5));
```

However, the challenge here is sometimes I may have 5 values (value1 ... value5), sometimes 10 (value1 ... value10) and sometimes twenty (value1 ... value20) depends on certain conditions.

How would I be able to bring this dynamic behavior here?

Like if values are 10 I should have

```
val orcLine:OrcStruct = OrcUtils.createOrcStruct(
                        typeInfo,
                        new Text(value1),
                        new Text(value2),
                        new Text(value3),
                        new Text(value4),
                        new Text(value5),
                        new Text(value6),
                        new Text(value7),
                        new Text(value8),
                        new Text(value9),
                        new Text(value10));
```

I may also have sometimes

```
val orcLine:OrcStruct = OrcUtils.createOrcStruct(
                       typeInfo,
                       new Text(value1),
                       new ShortWritable(Short.valueOf(value2)),
                       new LongWritable(Long.valueOf(value3)),
                       new DoubleWritable(Double.valueOf(value4)),
                       new FloatWritable(Float.valueOf(value5)));
```

I am currently using Scala version 2.11.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Variadic arguments? Or a list maybe?

Comment: Umm, how could I do that, code?

Comment: How do you determine how many values do you have?

Comment: Not a scala person, google dug this up: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-methods-variable-arguments-varargs-fields

Comment: I have a Map pre-populated which will let me know the column name and its respective value

Comment: @Nick Can you show that map?

Comment: Basically I was trying to do something like this https://codecheese.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/writing-an-orc-file-using-java/
but with dynamic behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your parameters are stored in list:

```
val params = List(
    new Text(value1),
    new ShortWritable(Short.valueOf(value2)),
    new LongWritable(Long.valueOf(value3)),
    new DoubleWritable(Double.valueOf(value4)),
    new FloatWritable(Float.valueOf(value5)))
)
```

As you probably noticed [OrcUtils.createOrcStruct](https://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.12.0/org/apache/crunch/types/orc/OrcUtils.html#createOrcStruct(org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfo,%20java.lang.Object...)) take variadic list of objects as second argument.

In order to pass the list as varargs in scala you need to use `:_*`. It would *"spread"* your list as varargs during method call:

```
OrcUtils.createOrcStruct(typeInfo, params:_*)
```